# Button labels disappearing in XIB-backed view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib, nib

I have a serious issue with a view that is defined by a XIB-file. It's a simple numeric entry pad with buttons for 0-9:

[image: Screenshot]

The problem is that in rare cases (as can be seen in the screenshot above), a button label is missing. It's not always the same label (in the example above, the "0" is missing). Usually closing the view and recreating it fixes the problem.

The XIB file's buttons are attached to UIButton controls in the view. The view is constructed like this:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button0;
// etc...
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button9;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [[UINib nibWithNibName:[[self class] description] bundle:nil]
                instantiateWithOwner:nil 
                options:nil
           ][0];

    if (self)
    {
        self.frame = frame;

        // ...
    }

    return self;
}
```

There's no controller involved and I also don't want that.

The view is created in code like this:

```
CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

When the issue occurs (which is not often and random), and a user taps on the button with the missing label, the titleLabel.text property of the button is `nil`:

```
- (IBAction) numberButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
   NSLog("button label = %@",button.titleLabel.text);

   // output: button label = (null)
}
```

The XML for the XIB file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="5056" systemVersion="13C64" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment defaultVersion="1536" identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3733"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="1" customClass="AmountEntryView">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="242" height="345"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="3" customClass="UIButton">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="56" width="80" height="56"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.80112777219999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="40"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="7">
                        <color key="titleColor" red="0.19607843459999999" green="0.30980393290000002" blue="0.52156865600000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                        <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </state>
                    <connections>
                        <action selector="numberButtonPressed:" destination="1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="142"/>
                    </connections>
                </button>

                <!-- ALL OTHER BUTTONS (omitted, as they are identical) -->

                <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" text="0.00" textAlignment="right" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="107">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="242" height="56"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.91557459679999997" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="32"/>
                    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.72580645160000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="button0" destination="86" id="108"/>
                <outlet property="button1" destination="58" id="109"/>
                <outlet property="button2" destination="60" id="110"/>
                <outlet property="button3" destination="59" id="111"/>
                <outlet property="button4" destination="30" id="112"/>
                <outlet property="button5" destination="32" id="113"/>
                <outlet property="button6" destination="31" id="114"/>
                <outlet property="button7" destination="3" id="115"/>
                <outlet property="button8" destination="19" id="116"/>
                <outlet property="button9" destination="8" id="117"/>
                <outlet property="buttonBack" destination="105" id="118"/>
                <outlet property="buttonDone" destination="106" id="119"/>
                <outlet property="buttonDot" destination="94" id="120"/>
                <outlet property="labelAmount" destination="107" id="133"/>
            </connections>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

I have no clue why this issue is occurring and I can't find anything similar reported here or anywhere else on the web.

Comment: You are accessing your button0 in your code anywhere and from there its text is changing if you can share your code i can guide you better.

Comment: Anything in debug log?

Comment: Nothing in the debug log, and the buttons are never accessed directly in code. It's not always the same button that loses its label.

Comment: Could you post your XIB here in XML format for us to try out ourselves?

Comment: Is the label missing as in there's no text, that it has `hidden` set to true, or that its frame is zero?

Comment: The text property becomes nil. The button itself is fine

Comment: I have added the XML of the XIB-file. (I removed all but one button element because they are all identical, apart from the location and label). Also, the IBOutlet-properties (button0-button9) are never used in the code (I could even leave them out completely)

Comment: Have you tried turning it on and off again? :-D Reinstalling XCode?
Is this only happening in the Simulator or on real Devices?

Comment: This happens randomly on real devices and in the simulator. When debugging and setting a breakpoint in one of the event handlers for the button presses, the "titleLabel.text" property of the button is ***nil*** (not the titleLabel itself, just the text property of the label)

Comment: The xib xml seems to be missing a `title="0"` etc...  This normally goes in the `<state> </state>` area.  If you add that tag inside of the xml manually, then open the file graphically and save it again, does it continue to happen?  Its happening on real and simulator because the look and feel is still based on the XML file which is missing information!!!

Comment: @trumpetlicks I left out all the other buttons to make the sample XML shorter. All the other buttons are identical to the first one (and as I've said in my question: it's not always the same button that loses the label)

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert - I also notice something else a bit odd considering you are using standard UIButtons, it is the portion within the initial `<button ...>` area named `customClass="UIButton"`  This tells me that you probably have `Custom` selected for the Button Type selector in Interface Builder.  I have seen this created weird behavior!!!

Comment: I understand you are creating these UIButtons in IB; in the XIB above you show a title only for the `UIControlStateNormal` state.  In IB there is a "state config" button where you can select other control states (highlighted, selected, disabled) and enter data for them; I would visit each state for each button and set the title for each.  In my experience the title and other data does not always reliably default to the normal state data, especially in low memory situations in the wild.

Comment: please share your entire project to take further test on it – the problem is too board, and any possible solution is mainly opinionbased only.

Comment: Are you using autolayout on the xib view? have you tried to print the recursiveDescription of the view to check if the button is just out of bounds?

Comment: Is your CustomView allocation being made on a secondary thread, or on the main thread? Have you debugged the view hierarchy using Xcode 6 (beta)?

Comment: @holex: I can't share the full project for IP reasons. It's not a personal project

Comment: @Andrea: not using autolayout, but that's definitely not the problem. As I mentioned, when I look at the titleLabel.text property, it is nil.

Comment: @BrunoWerminghoff: it's not accessed/created on a background thread.

Comment: I understand, but even if the property is nil(totally weird) it doesn't mean that the button is not somewhere in the hierarchy, I would check any way .

Comment: This won't like fix your issue, but it would be better IMO if you didn't replace self in your initWithFrame, and instead have a class factory method +customViewWithFrame: to create your object.  The pattern you have now double allocates CustomView.  The factory method would simply instantiate the CustomView directly from the nib, then set its frame.

Comment: How is the gradient effect being applied to each button?  The xib seems to say the background is solid gray but your screenshot shows a gradient.  Is some other code acting on the buttons to apply the gradient?  Could this code somehow be messing with the title in the button?

Comment: @TomSwift That's an old screenshot. I originally had a custom UIButton but that was my first suspect so I reverted to a standard UIButton. The problem didn't go away

Comment: Are you instantiating that view in code (calling alloc/init yourself) or is it loaded from another xib? As TomSwift mentioned, swapping out self can be a pain.

Comment: Can you try using RevealApp? It would definitely help to see if the view text is not empty, the button being nil or simply sent in the background. http://revealapp.com/

Comment: Have you tried over-riding the property, and seeing if anything sets it to nil? Also think its a bit odd that there aren't any other label objects in the XML - can you post all of it?

Comment: @DavidDoyle as I mentioned, the other buttons are identical, except for the label.

Comment: They won't be literally identical - the id property should definitely be different for each. I was just wondering if maybe the id properties were overlapping? They're supposed to be unique, but I don't know what happens if they aren't ....

Comment: @DavidDoyle Good point, although I wouldn't expect Xcode's XIB designer to generate duplicate IDs (but I checked just in case and they are unique)

Comment: @Eiko The view is created in code (as mentioned in my question)

Answer (score 2):

When setting the labels use:

```
[self.button0 setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

not:

```
self.button0.titleLabel.text = @"0";
```

This method will not retain the title set, i.e. the title disappears after the device is rotated etc.

**Other possible reasons:**

- Reduce the size of the font in the UIButtons. If a user uses the
  settings to use large dynamic font size, then the text may become to
  large to fit.
- Set up the UIView in code without the XIB.

**Sidenote:** 
You may also refer to the buttons by tags, then your code will become simpler as you don´t have to connect each button individually.

Comment: I'm not touching the label text in code, so that's not the issue. The label is set in the XIB file. What makes you think I'm setting titleLabel.text to a string in code?

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert because you are adding an outlet connection to each button. If you are not setting the title, what are you using the outlet for? I added this explanation because I experienced the same issue as you descriped and this was the reason.

Comment: I could easily drop the outlets (they're not referenced in code), but how would that make a difference?

Comment: Then use the outlets and set the button labels in the code as I show above. Check if it doesn´t solve the problem, if not let us know. The other reason for disappearing title may be if you change UIControlState (which is unlikely if you are not referencing the outlets to the buttons). But, please check this out before down voting me.

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't really read the question. Nowhere did I mention that the labels were set in code. Yet you tell me to set the labels in code in a different way. As to your suggestion: setting the labels in code wouldn't explain the behavior. It simply doesn't make sense that the labels ***sometimes*** disappear for no apparent reason. To make it worse, the problem occurs in very rare cases, and I haven't been able to reproduce it for weeks (although reports are still coming in from the field. The app has thousands of installs)

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert, I read the question and it says "The XIB file's buttons are attached to UIButton controls in the view.". Thus, I assumed the outlets shown in the code, were there for setting the title or something else for the UIButtons in code. You never stated in your question that the outlets are unnecessary and not being used. We can only assume from the code and text given. But one solution to your problem is to construct the CustomView in code.

Comment: Doing everything in code is my last resort. However, there must be some perfectly reasonable explanation why labels simply disappear. I asked this question here in the hope that someone may have experienced a similar issue. Simply avoiding the issue by rewriting everything in code will leave a bitter taste because I would never know what caused the issue in the first place.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert I agree with you that it would be comfortable to know the failure reason. But, in this case you want to make sure that things just work for the thousands of users, or bad comments build up. Another failure reason I just thought of might be if the users experiencing this are setting their "Text Size" in Settings. Then, the button labels may disappear when they no longer fit the UIButton.

Comment: I'd like to clarify some points. If a user sets a large dynamic font in the settings and the app changes accordingly is that because the code listen to a specific notification 'UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification'. I don't think that is a good suggestion to do not use xib and set up the view with code. Xib are a really useful and time effective production instrument, we just need to learn and understand them.

Comment: @Andrea I am not against using xib, but in this case there is an unknown rare error. I don´t think that his lack of understanding xib is causing the error. He cannot find anything wrong with the xib, thus, I suggest to build the view in code. Codin time is not an issue here, but getting rid of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is really weird as I said in the comments, but this not the first time that I need to recreate a xib from scratch, cause of some strange problems.

Once someone told me to do not swap `self` inside the init method, even if I don't think this will solve the problem I'd like to give you two different ways to load xibs.

The first one:
Probably is the one that you can try just changing one line of code. Supposing that in your xib the view has as custom class  `CustomView` and the outlets are connected here and File owner is nil. Try to load that like this:

```
CustomView *view =[[UINib nibWithNibName:[NSStringFromClass(self.class) bundle:nil] instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil][0];
```

This will trigger the loading process from a xib and it takes its root object, is the same that probably used with cell prototypes in table views. If you need to do some sort of initialization do it inside `-awakeFromNib` 'cause `initWithFrame` will not be called.
 The proper method to get the class name is not `-description` since it just gaves info about the object, in the future it can change (unlikely), the is the `NSStringFromClass` to get just the class name as a string.
The second:
Create a xib, with the file's owner set to an instance of CustomView, make your connect with the fil's owner, load the xib and add it as a subview.
Here is a small class that I use as an abstract class to create view that uses a xib.

```
@interface NibbedView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView * nibView;

- (instancetype) initWithNibName: (NSString*) nibViewName;
- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame  andNibName: (NSString*) nibViewName;

- (void) loadNibWithName: (NSString*) nibName;


@end
```

and implementation:

```
@interface NibbedView ()
@end

@implementation NibbedView

-(void) setContstraints {
    _nibView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_nibView);
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_nibView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_nibView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
}

- (instancetype) initWithNibName: (NSString*) nibViewName{
    if (self = [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero]) {
        if (nibViewName) {
            [self loadNibWithName:nibViewName];
        }

    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        //
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame  andNibName: (NSString*) nibViewName{
    if (self = [self initWithFrame:frame]) {
        if (nibViewName) {
            [self loadNibWithName:nibViewName];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) loadNibWithName: (NSString*) nibName {
    if (_nibView) {
        [_nibView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: nibName owner: self options: nil];
        _nibView.frame = self.bounds;
        [self addSubview:_nibView];
        [self setContstraints];
    }

}


@end
```

It uses auto layout to make the xib view to stretch all over the CustomView root view.
As I said try in the debugger to make a `-recursiveDescription` of the root view, even if is not connected maybe is somewhere in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really say what is causing the behaviour you describe, but I would like to suggest a way to try and get some clue at what is happening, since you cannot share your project. You can try out any of the approaches below, all of them aimed at finding out when `text` becomes `nil`; I list them in order of growing complexity:

1. add a KVO observer for the `button.titleLabel.text` property; if this does not work,
2. swizzle the `UILabel` `setText:` method with your own implementation; if this does not work,
3. enter the debugger and set a watch on the memory location of `button.titleLabel.text` (for all your buttons, at creation time).

Hopefully, one of these methods will let you break into your app when `text` becomes `nil` so that by inspecting the call stack you may find out what is causing the issue.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:button0];

might help you.

Answer (score -1):

I have never loaded or seen someone loading a Nib like that.

Try using the more standard `[NSBundle.mainBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]`.

Comment: do you know any problems(disadvantages) that `UINib nibWithNibName:bundle:` can cause?

Comment: UINib was introduced in iOS4 (or 5), the main difference is that the xib is cached. Is totally fine to load it using that method.

Comment: I agree that the way the nib is being loaded is odd, but it isn't actually an answer to his question.

Comment: I would still give it a try. There may be some differences in the way objects are deserialized with both methods.

Answer (score -1):

In XIB, check to see that all your `UIButtons` have their `Title` property set to `Plain` rather than `Attributed`.

The problem is that a button or label's `text` is different from its `attributedText`, and if both are set, then sometimes no text will show at all. Try testing this to see if there is any attributed text:

```
- (IBAction)numberButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"%@", self.setButton.titleLabel.attributedText);
}
```

Using attributed vs plain text is the difference between:

```
[self.button0 setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"0"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.button0 setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I will investigate, but I double-checked the XIB file and all UIButton s are set to plain